# Google App Engine/WSGIApplication: How to check debug?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In the `WSGIApplication`'s constructor, it takes a `debug` argument. Is there a way to access the value set for this from the the handler classes that inherit from `webapp.RequestHandler`?

```
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', fooHandler)
                                          ],
                                        debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
```

Answer (score 1):

A WSGIApplication instance records the value of the `debug` parameter as `self.__debug`: the double underscore is a **strong** indication that no code outside the class itself is supposed to look at this attribute, as it's considered an internal application detail and could change "at any time" (even in a minor revision of the API).  If you want to ignore this extremely strong indication, you *could*, technically, use `webapp.WSGIApplication.active_instance._WSGIApplication__debug` to look at it, but it's a truly bad idea.

A *much* better idea is to subclass `WSGIApplication` in your own code to make the attribute publically visible:

```
class MyWSGIapp(webapp.WSGIApplication):
    def __init__(self, url_mapping, debug=False):
        self.debugmode = debug
        webapp.WSGIApplication.__init__(self, url_mapping, debug)
```

Now, when you use `MyWSGIapp` instead of `webapp.WSGIApplication` to start things off, `webapp.WSGIApplication.active_instance.debugmode` becomes a *clean*, *solid* way to access the attribute of interest from wherever else in your application.

Comment: So, I'm breaking encapsulation by subclassing... isn't this almost as dangerous as just reading the value directly in the first place?

Comment: This suggestion doesn't break encapsulation, and it isn't dangerous - you can rely on `debugmode` being there because you control that code (unlike trying to access `WSGIApplication`'s `__debug` field directly).

Comment: @Rosarch, I'm confused -- where ever did you read or otherwise "learn" that subclassing breaks encapsulation?!  Subclassing is a fundamental thing in OOP and the subclass I suggested doesn't even peek at _any_ attribute of the base class, it just "captures" a copy of an `__init__` argument on the fly -- how could it **possibly** be **at all** "encapsulation-breaking"? Please clarify your worry.

Comment: looks like I read over your example too quickly. The method you use, of copying the example, is fine. What I thought you meant was "subclass the base, then use public getters for members that are protected in the base." (using Java terms there). The latter seems like a poor idea, but the former, which you suggested, makes sense.

Comment: @Rosarch, thanks for clarifying.  If the attribute was "protected" (single underscore at the start of the name) it would be usefully accessible from subclasses, but the debug attribute is "private" (double underscore at the start of the name) which means "hands off, **every**body!", so of course using a subclass to access it would make no sense (and no difference) -- and my approach was, as you now see, a very different one. I think the exchange was instructive, so, thanks!